# In a closed monoidal category $\mathcal{V}$ is the adjunction $\mathcal{V}$-natural?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a closed symmetric monoidal category. By definition we have a natural isomorphism of hom-sets
$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{V}}(X\otimes Y,Z) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{V}}(X,\mathcal{V}(Y,Z))$.

Viewing $\mathcal{V}$ as a $\mathcal{V}$-category one can show that $-\otimes -:\mathcal{V}\times \mathcal{V}\to \mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{V}(-,-):\mathcal{V}^{op} \times \mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{V}$ are $\mathcal{V}$-functors.

Is it also true that they form a $\mathcal{V}$-adjunction in general?

Meaning we have a $\mathcal{V}$-natural isomorphism
$\Phi_{X,Z}:\mathcal{V}(X\otimes Y,Z) \to \mathcal{V}(X,\mathcal{V}(Y,Z))$ i.e. satisfying
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{V}(X\otimes Y,Z) @>{\Phi}>> \mathcal{V}(X,\mathcal{V}(Y,Z))\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathcal{V}(X'\otimes Y,Z') @>{\Phi}>> \mathcal{V}(X',\mathcal{V}(Y,Z'))
\end{CD}$$
for any morphisms $g:X'\to X$ and $h:Z\to Z'$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is established in 1.8(j) of Kelly's [Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html).